Excel - create a list from a data column but ignore/remove blank cells
I am trying to build a massive keyword database for Google Ads, using Excel to substitute one keyword for another, which has already saved countless hours.
Because the data set I am working with will contain anywhere from 5-30 keyword sets that need to be recreated, the current structure I am using creates numerous blank cells between the keyword sets.  I am trying to optimize the process further with a condensed list of data, ignoring all blank cells, so I can copy/paste all of the finished keywords into another spreadsheet.
The issue I am facing is only the first data entry in the list is being copied over.
keyword data replacement list

I have tried the following variations:
=IFERROR(INDEX($I$2:$I$20,SMALL(IF(TRIM($I$2:$I$20)<>"",ROW($I$2:$I$20)-ROW($I$2)+1),ROWS($I$2:$I$20))),"")
=IFERROR(INDEX($I$2:$I$20,SMALL(IF($I$2:$I$20<>"",ROW($I$2:$I$20)-1),ROW(A1))),"")
=IFERROR(INDEX($I$2:$I$20,SMALL(IF($I$2:$I$20<>"",ROW($I$2:$I$20)-ROW($I$2)+1,""),ROW(A2)-ROW($A$2)+1)),"")
However, as previously stated, only the first value is displayed in the list once the formula has been dragged down the column.
only first value displaying

I also tried another variation found here:
=IFERROR(INDEX($I$2:$I$20,SMALL(INDEX(($I$2:$I$20<>"")*ROW($I$2:$I$20),0),COUNTBLANK($I$2:$I$20)+ROW(I2))),"")
This gets me closer to what I am looking to do, showing more results, but it still includes the blank cells and is missing a few data entries.
data still missing


What is your Excel version? Use FILTER() function.

It seems Column I is your input data. Which one is your desired output, D2:F4?

It looks like your goal is to combine lists in D-F without blanks, and in column "DATA" you have already combined the values from D-F, but with blanks; the formula(s) tried were to remove blanks in "DATA".
Assuming you have an older version of Excel ( SMALL was used in formulas in earlier version to remove blanks), here's a formula, based on the ones you tried:

select J2:J20 , with top one as the active cell (which usually the case)
enter the following in the formula bar
press Control + Shift + Enter - there's no need to fill down
Here's reference for array formulas: Create an array formula - Microsoft Support

=IF(
    ROW(I2:I20) < ROW($I$2) + ROWS($I$2:$I$20) - COUNTBLANK($I$2:$I$20),
    INDEX(
        $I$2:$I$20,
        SMALL(
            IF(
                ($I$2:$I$20 <> ""),
                ($I$2:$I$20 <> "") * ROW($I$2:$I$20),
                ""
            ),
            ROW(I2:I20) - 1
        ) - 1,
        1
    ),
    ""
)



With Microsoft 365
It is very easy to combine (append) multiple columns into single column, while removing blanks, with TOCOL:
=TOCOL(D2:F8, 1, TRUE)


Please let me know if you need explanation for how the first formula works.

If you are on most recent versions of Excel then use FILTER() function. Try-
=FILTER($I$2:$I$17,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(D1,$I$2:$I$17)))

Put above formula to D2 cell and drag to right till F2.

